# How to I use several buttons in html to set values for my website and then one button that submits all the data?

Tags: php, html, button, web

I'm looking to have several buttons in my php website that set different values based on the button selected and then have the final button set a value and then submit all of these to the next php page. So here I have two sets of buttons that need to be set inside of a form:

```
<form id="formUploadFile"  action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" > 
    <p> 
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>"> 
    </p> 

    <p align="left"> 
        <label for="file" >First, Choose your image!</label> 
        <input type="file" name="files[]"  /> 
    </p> 

    <p>
        <h5>Would you like to use colored pencils or paint?</h5>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="ToolChoice" value="0">Colored Pencils</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="ToolChoice" value="1">Paint</button>
          </div>
    </p>
    <p class="text-center"> 
        <h5>Then, Choose your Difficulty!</h5>
            <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="DifficultyChoice" value="0" onclick="loadingCircle()">Kids</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="DifficultyChoice" value="1" onclick="loadingCircle()">Novice</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="DifficultyChoice" value="2" onclick="loadingCircle()">Intermediate</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="DifficultyChoice" value="3" onclick="loadingCircle()">Advanced</button>
          </div>

    </p> 

    </form>
```

I want the user to first choose their "ToolChoice" and then choose their "DifficultyChoice" and to have both values posted to the $uploadHandler. However, as written, only the "DifficultyChoice is being sent. On the php end I'm just using

```
$difficulty=$_POST['DifficultyChoice'];
$toolChoice=$_POST['ToolChoice'];
```

I understand this is because I'm not using submit for the toolchoice, but I do not want to run the php $uploadHandler for each of these values separately. Rather, I need both set and sent at the same time.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `javscript` for the handling of the submit event. The storing of the program state can be done in various ways. In this example I used two hidden fields to store the values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="DifficultyChoice" id="hiddDiff" value="-1" />
<input type="hidden" name="toolChoice" id="hiddTool" value="-1" />
```

I made two functions `changeDifficulty` and `changeTools` which are being passed an `int` and they set the values of the `hidden fields` as well.

`Hidden fields` are used because they have a `name` which will be passed to the receiving `PHP` file. So you don't have to use `names` on each `button`. Instead let `javascript` do it for you with `two functions` and `two hidden fields`:

**EDIT:** I replaced the original answer for a working example since the OP asked for the receiving server side as well.

The program consists of two `PHP` files `a_test.php` and `b_tesp.php`, and one `javascript` file `a_test.js`. They should be all located in the same folder for this example to work.

**Program sequence:** `a_test.php` will send `POST` data to `b_test.php` using `a_test.js`. `b_test.php` will receive the data and try to validate it. If everything is ok the image will be uploaded, otherwise you will see an error message.

**Here is the code:**

File `a_test.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="a_test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="formUploadFile" name="formUploadFile" action="b_test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" > 

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">

    <p align="left"> 
    <label for="file" >First, Choose your image!</label> 
    <input type="file" name="img_1"  /> 
    </p> 

    <h5>Would you like to use colored pencils or paint?</h5>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Colored Pencils" onclick="changeTools(0)" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Paint" onclick="changeTools(1)" />
    </div>

    <h5>Then, Choose your Difficulty!</h5>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Kids" onclick= "changeDifficulty(0)" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Novice" onclick="changeDifficulty(1)" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Intermediate" onclick="changeDifficulty(2)" />
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Advanced" onclick="changeDifficulty(3)" />
   </div>

   <input type="hidden" name="difficultyChoice" id="hiddDiff" value="-1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="toolChoice" id="hiddTool" value="-1" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

File `a_test.js`:

```
function changeDifficulty(number)
{
   var toolChoice = parseInt(document.getElementById('hiddTool').value)
   var difficulty = document.getElementById('hiddDiff');
   var form = document.getElementById('formUploadFile');
   difficulty.value = number;

   // if the toolChoice is set
   if(toolChoice != -1)
   {
      // Show the values, for testing purposes
      console.log("Tools: " + toolChoice + " Difficulty: " + difficulty.value);
      form.submit();
   }
}

function changeTools(number)
{
   var difficulty = parseInt(document.getElementById('hiddDiff').value)
   var toolChoice = document.getElementById('hiddTool');
   var form = document.getElementById('formUploadFile');
   toolChoice.value = number;

   // If the difficulty is set
   if(difficulty != -1)
   {
      console.log("Tools: " + toolChoice.value + " Difficulty: " + difficulty);
      form.submit();
   }
}
```

File `b_test.php`:

```
<?php

// make a function to check if `int` so you don't have to retype for each variable
function checkIfInt($var)
{
    // Here we use a fix to let `0` also be validated as `int`
    if (filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) || filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === 0)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


function checkImageValidityAndUpload()
{
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if($_FILES["img_1"]["error"] == 0)
    {
       // allowed image types
       $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
       // some (incoming) file properties
       $filename = $_FILES["img_1"]["name"];
       $filetype = $_FILES["img_1"]["type"];
       $filesize = $_FILES["img_1"]["size"];

       // Verify file extension (here we are comparing the file extension to the keys of $allowed array)
       $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed))
       {
          echo "Error: Please select a valid file format.<br/>";
          return false;
       }

       // Verify file size - 5MB maximum (5MB is example, you can set anything)
       $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
       if($filesize > $maxsize) 
       {
          echo "Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.<br/>";
          return false;
       }

       // Verify MYME type of the file (here we are comparing the file MYME type to the $allowed array values)
       if(in_array($filetype, $allowed))
       {
          // Check whether file exists before uploading it (upload/ is example folder, change to your image folder)
          if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["img_1"]["name"]))
          {
              echo $_FILES["img_1"]["name"] . " already exists.<br/>";
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_1"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["img_1"]["name"]);
              return true;
          } 
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.<br/>";
          return false;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["img_1"]["error"]."<br/>";
      return false;
   }
}



// MAIN program starts here - Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   $tools = array("Colored Pencils", "Paint");
   $difficulties = array("Kids", "Novice", "Intermediate", "Advanced");

   // check if all needed variables are set and valid, and if the image is valid and uploaded successfully
   if(isset($_POST['difficultyChoice']) && isset($_POST['toolChoice']) && isset($_FILES['img_1']) && 
      checkIfInt($_POST['difficultyChoice']) && checkIfInt($_POST['toolChoice']) && 
      checkImageValidityAndUpload())
   {
      $diff = intval($_POST['difficultyChoice']);
      $tool = intval($_POST['toolChoice']);
      echo 'Tools choice: '.$tools[$tool].' Difficulty choice: '.$difficulties[$diff].'<br/>';
      echo 'image has been uploaded successfully';
      // do something
  }
  else
  {
      echo 'Something went wrong. Program will not continue';
      die();
  }
}
else
{
   echo 'There was no POST request.';
   die();
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the way this is written, its causing the button to get reset to the value -1 every time I select the other button. I think this is because at the beginning of each function, we are setting the variables by the element ID, and the only area where the element ids are, they values are set to -1?  Also, what is the method for getting the value of these buttons from the php site?

Comment: @clutch1020 Ok, I will now upload a working example (I just tested it) of an example file `a_test.php` that will submit the image, difficultyChoice, and toolChoice to a file called `b_test.php`. File `a_test.php` uses a javascript file `a_test.js`. Put all of these files in the same folder. Read the comments I left in `b_test.php` to understand how the program works on the receiving side. Set your `upload folder` to an existing one as the program does not check if the folder exists.

Comment: @clutch1020 Ok. I edited. Just `copy/paste` the code into new  files and give them the file names I provided to see it working. The mass of code in the server side (`b_test.php`) is needed because uploading an image is a big security risk and should be properly checked.

Comment: @clutch1020 I edited so you can see the selected string values on the server side not the number values, as it was until now.

Comment: @clutch1020 No problem, glad it worked for you :) Peace

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use JavaScript and use the onclick attribute in which would change the button's value to what you need it to be to check if it's active when the whole thing is submitted to the actual PHP page. Having the buttons with the same name attributes will never work. You should rather give each a different name attribute for each and use JavaScript to change the value to "active" on click and then you want to check all the different $_POSTs sent. So for example you name the first difficulty "Difficulty1", 
`if ($_POST['Difficulty1'] === 'active') { // They chose this difficulty }`

Comment: Actually scratch that, misread what you needed. So basically you still want the other buttons for DifficultyChoice to be different, but instead of the values being what they are now, change them to what the user picks with ToolChoice using JavaScript. Then the value of all the difficultychoices will be your toolchoice you needed to get.